# TCL : regexp for Grammar of ANSI C++ Declarations

Tags: tcl

I am a beginner in TCL and trying to write a TCL script to parse and print out all lines in a C++ code file which is used for variable declarations. Till Now I am able to detect and print all statements inside a block {}. Now I understand that the different variable declarations format in Ansi C++ modules could be:

```
int  x;
int  y=9;
int  x,y;
int  x,y=0;
int  x,y=0,c;
short const x=9;
int* x,y,c=null;
short const *x=NULL;
MyObj aobj();
MyObj aobj(x,y);
Myobj * a = dynamic_cast<A *>(b);
String x = "test";
```

I am not sure if I missed any.

What I am doing is that I am splitting the line :

```
if { [ string equal $lineType "statement" ] == 1 } {
        puts $lineValue
        set wordList [regexp -inline -all -- {\S+} $lineValue]
}
```

to verify the below format by different values at its list index:

```
qualifier varaiablename = value;
qualifier varaiablename;
qualifier varaiablename = value, variablename;
```

But I am not able to achieve it. I believe that TCL regexp would help us here to achieve the objective. However I am unable to conclude of what regexp expression I should use / code here.

I want to avoid looking for C++ defined data types / keywords but look for a specific format in string which is actually a C++ statement:

```
qualifier type name;
qualifier type name, name2;
qualifier type name = value;
```

or rather

```
word word word;
word word word, word;
word word word = integer, word = word;
```

As per the declarations format mentioned above.

Please provide your valuable thoughts / input.

Comment: You'd be better off using a proper parser; the language of C++ declarations is non-trivial…

Comment: Note that no one prevents you from placing a newline instead of a space in the `int x ;` declaration, so it's more involved.

Answer (score 0):

There is [C/C++ tokenizer](https://github.com/CorsixTH/CorsixTH/blob/master/LDocGen/c_tokenise.lua) which uses an LPEG grammar for turning a C/C++ file into an array of tokens, and also has code for pretty printing a token array as 
HTML.

[ltcl](http://www.tset.de/ltcltk/README_ltcl.html), a simple binding of the Tcl interpreter to Lua, can be used to integrate it.